# Yii2 как правильно написать запрос с Inner join?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

По сути я хочу написать запрос

> SELECT * FROM 'threads' INNER JOIN 'users' ON 'threads.author_id'='users.id'

Но мой вариант

```html
$threads = $query->join('INNER JOIN', 'users', 'users.id = threads.author_id')
            ->orderBy('thread_id')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();
```

Почему-то выводит только часть из таблицы Threads. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ->innerJoin('users', 'threads.author_id'='users.id')
```